# How to read a textfile line by line from FTP server?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, filestream

I have wriiten some code for reading **textfiles** from **ftp server**, without downloading to the local system. Now i need to display it line by line.. is it possible?

```
  WebClient request = new WebClient();
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "edddd");
    byte[] newFileData = request.DownloadData(url);
    string fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
   ListBox1.Items.Add(fileString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Split your file contents on new line.

```
var lines = fileString.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, 
                                   StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Then use the array of lines returned to display as your line. Each could be an item in your list box.

Comment: but it shows an error cant convert string[] to string @nunespascal

Comment: You have to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) String.Split overload. What did you use?

Comment: Obviously you can't do that. `lines` is an array of strings. Run a loop and add each line to your listbox.

Comment: but when i run this remotely it doesnt read the text file..showing an error : Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.. but runs properly on local host. Can you help ? @nunespascal

Comment: The account under which you are running this doesn't have permissions to make http or ftp requests. Happens in sandboxed environments. Ask a different question specifying what you uploaded where and what error you got. You will surely get an answer.